# masking url with godaddy

Tags: wordpress

I have purchased a domain name from godaddy. I want to be able to have that domain point to my NAS with wordpress installed. the URL of the wordpress being:

```
http://somedomain.asuscomm.com/WordPress/
```

(Notice I'm using asuscomm.com Dynamic DNS that came with my Asus router)
All this works and going to

```
 http://somedomain.asuscomm.com/WordPress/
```

loads my wordpress blog.

**On godaddy's website**: Domains => Manage DNS => Forwarding => somedomain.asuscomm.com/wordpress/

Option 1: Forward Only - correctly forwards to my domain however clicking on the link within the blog changes the domain from NewGoDaddyDomain.com to => http://somedomain.asuscomm.com/WordPress/

Option 2: Forward with masking - forwards to domain however browsing within the blog doesn't work as the URL stays at NewGoDaddyDomain.com

How can I set it up so that it only Masks the first part of the URL, meaning:

> This: http://somedomain.asuscomm.com/WordPress/category/solid/
>
> To This: NewGoDaddyDomain.com/category/solid/

Answer (score 0):

This wordpress plugin might work for you. This plugin allows you to have multiple host names in the database.

[Any Hostname Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/any-hostname/)

this way the database knows both urls, and you might be able to use option 2 forward with masking. Just a thought.